# Running git rm -r --cached on Windows

Tags: windows, git

This command doesn't seem to work on Windows. When I enter the command

```
git rm -r --cached.
```

This is what I get

```
usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...

-n, --dry-run         dry run
-q, --quiet           do not list removed files
--cached              only remove from the index
-f, --force           override the up-to-date check
-r                    allow recursive removal
--ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
```

Help??

Comment: Did you forget to put a space between `--cached` and `.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `-r` requires a a directory as noted in the docs:

> **-r**
>   Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

Try e.g.

```
git rm -r --cached ./
```

Comment: I'm not too sure on that - I think you'll find `.` is a directory regardless of whether it has a trailing backslash on it.

Comment: Yeah your right. Dumb mistake added * after a space and it worked. Doh!!! Will mark your answer once I'm allowed to.

Comment: That's true and it is not the difference my answer is about. I just did not interpret the author's trailing '.' as part of his command :) I am still curios whether he just forgot to insert a space or if it is part of a 'sentence' ... we will see :)

Answer (score 3):

If your command truly *is:*

```
git rm -r --cached.
```

then you need a space between `--cached` (the flag) and `.` (the directory), just like it says in the usage line:

```
usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...
                              ^
                              |
                              +-- right here.
```

I'd test it to be sure but I'm not in the habit of running random commands that may damage my current repo state :-)

---

If your command is:

```
git rm -r --cached
```

and the `.` is simply a misplaced period indicating end of the sentence then, as per the usage line above, you are *required* to provide a file name to it (the `<file>` is *not* optional).

In that case, you can use `.` to include the current directory or provide a list of filenames if you need to just do some of the files.

---

If neither of those are the case, please let us know and we can investigate it further. Of course, if one of those *is* the case, this question should probably be closed as a simple typo.